# How big is the NXT blockchain in disk usage compared to the Bitcoin Blockchain as of June 2014? And rate of increase?

Tags: blockchain, nxt

Currently I'm looking for the disk usage size of the NXT and Bitcoin blockchain size as of June 2014 and the current rate of of increase every day/week/year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of today June 29, 2014. NXT Blockchain takes up 512MB. and the value is at 5-7 cents per nxt.

[image]